# Certain position in a string

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
char password[10];
int i;
int contor=0;
printf("introdu parola ");
scanf("%c",&password);
for(i=0;i>=10;i++)
{
    if (isalpha(password[1])) contor=1;


}
 if(contor=1) {printf("good pass");}
    else {printf("bad pass");}
return 0;
}
```

I have this piece of code.

I want ,if I type

> 22s33

to print

> good pass

else

> bad pass

How can I verify a certain position in a `char` array? The method above seems to not work. Can someone explain me why my logic is incorrect?
//Edit: i`ve corrected it.Seems to work well.Thanks guys

Comment: @crt01 ___Please don't edit question to add the answer___. You can either add you own answer, or [accept an already existing one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062), if it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple problems, some of them are very *basic concepts*. Suggest re-reading the C book.

To provide some hints,

1. `scanf("%c",&password);` should be `scanf("%9s",&password);`

   *Details:* `%c` reads and stores a single `char`, for a *string*, you need `%s`. The `9` is to denote the max field width to avoid buffer overflow by longer-than-expected-input.
2. `for(i=0;i>=10;i++)` should be `for(i=0; i<10; i++)` and, not required altogether.

   *Details:* Check the value of `i` using a debugger and step-by-step execution. Moreover, if you're looking for a particular index, why loop, at all?
3. `if(contor=1)` should be `if(contor == 1)`

   *Details:* `=` is the assignment operator, whereas, what you need , is comparison, the `==` operator.

etc.

---

EDIT: Update by OP,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

 char password[10];
 int i;
 int contor=0;

 printf("introdu parola ");
 scanf("%s",&password);

 for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
   if (isalpha(password[1])) contor=1; 
 }

 if(contor==1) {
   printf("good pass");
 } 
 else {
   printf("bad pass");
 } 

 return 0; 
}
```

Comments: This is better, but still needs improvement.

- `scanf("%s",&password);` should better be `scanf("%9s",password);`
- `for(i=0;i<10;i++) { if (isalpha(password[1])) contor=1; }` is meaningless, you never used `i` meaningfully in the loop. In case, you want to check for the second (*or third?*) element only, you can skip the loop and write directly

  ```
  if (isalpha(password[1]) {
       /*print good password*/
  } 
  else {
       /* print bad password*/
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice that you provided hints and did not feed him the solution.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur I'm saving _myself_, "feed" the solution and be ready to see a follow up question. :P

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main()
    {
    char password[10];
    int i;
    int contor=0;
    printf("introdu parola ");
    scanf("%s",&password);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(password[1])) contor=1;


    }
    if(contor==1) {printf("good pass");}
        else {printf("bad pass");}
    return 0;
    }
I`ve corrected it.Thanks for answers.